# Mutating the DOM with elements including different indexable variables

Tags: javascript, html

Hope my title isn't misleading! 
In my quest discovering the power of loops, I would like to sort this:

I need to build these elements:

```
<div id="my-id">
  <div class="my-class">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" value="a">
    <label for="checkbox-1">A</label>
  </div>
  <div class="my-class">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" value="b">
    <label for="checkbox-2">B</label>
  </div>
  <div class="my-class">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" value="c">
    <label for="checkbox-3">C</label>
  </div>
<!-- etc, 9 more -->
</div>
```

I did this so far but don't know how to proceed to get the alphabet letters (both lower and uppercase) in the element.

```
const alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]; 

  let html = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    html += `<div class = "my-class">
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox-${i}" value = "?">
                <label for = "checkbox-${i}">??`;
    html += "</label></div>";
  }
  $("#here").html(html);
```

Is there a good way, or just hardcoding in the HTML file will be easier? (it's 12 inputs in total).

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/DangerousPinkFrontpage)

```
const alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]; 

let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
  let checkboxID = 'checkbox-'.concat(String(i).toLowerCase())
  let checkboxValue = alphabet[i]
  html += `
    <div class = "my-class">
      <input type="checkbox" id="${checkboxID}" value="${checkboxValue}">
      <label for="${checkboxID}">${checkboxValue}</label>
    </div>`;
}
```

or use `Array.reduce`...

```
const html = alphabet.reduce((_html, letter, letterIndex) => {
  let checkboxID = 'checkbox-'.concat(String(letterIndex).toLowerCase())
  let checkboxValue = letter
  return _html += `
    <div class = "my-class">
      <input type="checkbox" id="${checkboxID}" value="${checkboxValue}">
      <label for="${checkboxID}">${checkboxValue}</label>
    </div>
  `
}, '')
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much! Just changed a little thing to have the value lowercase and increased checkboxID by 1 to start from 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your alphabet array, and use alphabet[i] to access the desired letter. Then you can put it in both the value attribute, and into your label.

If you need a lower case version, you use `.toLowerCase()`

```
 for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    html += `<div class = "my-class">
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox-${i}" value = "${alphabet[i].toLowerCase()}">
                <label for = "checkbox-${i}">${alphabet[i]}</label></div>`;
  }
```